# WPF GroupStyle only for Groups with more than 1 item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am trying to show different Groups in a Listview which contain an expander and a header. However I don't want my SecondLevel Group to show a header if the Group only contains 1 item.
Since this would be quite inconvenient.
My Code:

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewGrouping.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:listViewGrouping="clr-namespace:ListViewGrouping"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
    <listViewGrouping:GroupItemStyleSelector x:Key="groupItemStyleSelector"/>
    <!-- Style for the first level GroupItem -->
        <Style x:Key="FirstLevel" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="3.5,0" Text="{Binding Name}" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="3.5,0" Text="Elements:"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="3.5,0" Text="{Binding ItemCount}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <!-- Style for the second level GroupItem -->
        <Style x:Key="SecondLevel" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Expander IsExpanded="True" Margin="15,0,0,0">
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="mailView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource groupItemStyleSelector}" />
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Subject}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Sender" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Sender}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Support-ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Support_ID}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Supporter" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Supporter}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Received" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReceivedDate}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
    private void createMailList()
    {
        _mails.Add(new Mail("LIC", "Lizenz geht nicht", "Xeun", "LIC.2013.01.10.002", "Xeun", "25.09.2013"));
        _mails.Add(new Mail("CD", "Alles doof", "Xeun", "CD.2013.01.10.002", "Xeun", "25.09.2013"));
        _mails.Add(new Mail("CD", "Re:Alles doof", "Xeun", "CD.2013.01.10.002", "Xeun", "25.09.2013"));
        _mails.Add(new Mail("CD", "CD kaputt", "Xeun", "CD.2013.01.10.003", "Xeun", "25.09.2013"));
        _mails.Add(new Mail("CD", "Geht nicht", "Xeun", "CD.2013.01.10.001", "Xeun", "25.09.2013"));
        _mails.Add(new Mail("LIC", "Kaputt", "Xeun", "LIC.2013.01.10.001", "Xeun", "25.09.2013"));
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        createMailList();
        DataContext = _mails;
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_mails);
        PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("ID");
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Support_ID"));
    }

}
public class GroupItemStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        Style s;

        CollectionViewGroup group = item as CollectionViewGroup;
        Window window = Application.Current.MainWindow;

        if (!group.IsBottomLevel)
        {
            s = window.FindResource("FirstLevel") as Style;
        }
        else
        {
            s = window.FindResource("SecondLevel") as Style;
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

I hope I explained my problem well enough - I have attached a screenshot of the small app - the Groups marked as red only contain one item and should not be shown as group.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: As a side note, this is not going to function properly. You can see in the image that your Expander elements cause the items to line up incorrectly with their column headers. Consider a converter that calculates the difference in the X coordinate of the column presenter and the expander content and applies a negative margin. That still won't give you a perfect control but it will line the content up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. For both styles split the ControlTemplate in 2, one with an expander and one with out.
2. Create a converter which checks the if the group size (your group is of type CollectionViewGroup)

   ```
    return yourGroup.Items.Count > 1
   ```
3. Place a DataTrigger as seen below in each style which checks the groups size via the converter
   (your DataContext is your group so the binding is  Binding="{Binding}"

xaml :

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}" x:Key="withExpander">
     <Expander IsExpanded="True">
         <Expander.Header>
               .....
         </Expander.Header>
         <ItemsPresenter />
      </Expander>
  </ControlTemplate>


  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}" x:Key="withOutExpander">        
        <ItemsPresenter />          
  </ControlTemplate>

  <Style x:Key="FirstLevel" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
      <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource withExpander}" />

      <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding , Converter={StaticResource GroupSizeToExpanderConverter}" Value="False">
                  <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource withOutExpander}"/>
          </DataTrigger>    
      </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

Edit  :

*the converter value will be the Group itself (of type CollectionViewGroup)

The Converter  :

```
public class GroupSizeToExpanderConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CollectionViewGroup grp = (CollectionViewGroup)value;
        return grp.Items.Count() > 1; // ALTERNATIVLY grp.ItemCount;             
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please go a bit more into the Converter which is needed?
I am not quite sure how to implement this thing.
Thanks a lot

Comment: I think the check in the converter should read `return grp.ItemCount > 1` ("bigger than one" rather than "bigger than zero"). Great answer!

Comment: @JonasChapuis your right didn't notice that , when i explained it above the code i did say > 1 though ..Any way i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution

```
<GroupStyle>
<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                            <Expander.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Expander">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemCount}" Value="1">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Expander.Style>
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                    <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <Border BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0 2">
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </Expander>
                        <ItemsPresenter>
                            <ItemsPresenter.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ItemsPresenter">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemCount}" Value="1">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ItemsPresenter.Style>
                        </ItemsPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
```